# Issue with manual bootstrapping and overriding angular services in config

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-service

I am trying to get my angular application work in live mode as well as in a prototype mode just by overriding the services. As a part of this when the prototype mode is turned on in the config, i halt the bootstrap process, load mock services (js) files and resume bootstrapping.

Here is a simplified list of source code for preparing the **[demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/tChomn?p=preview)**:-

**App.js**

*Just my app, which for simulation calls the service and display the result. It required `StubApp` as well whose provide this is going to use to override the services*

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['StubsApp'])

.run([ '$rootScope', 'DataService', function($scope, DataService){
   DataService.getData().then(function(data){
    $scope.name = data;
  });
}]);
```

**DataService.js**

*Just a simple service registered with the app.*

```
function DataService($q){
  this.getData = function(){
       return $q.when('I am Real!!');
  }
}
DataService.$inject = ['$q'];
angular.module('app').service('DataService',DataService);
```

**Driver.js**

Just the config registration which will set up mocking.

```
angular.module('app').config(['$provide', 'stubServiceProvider', 'AppConfig', function($provide, stubProvider, AppConfig){
    if(AppConfig.StubEnabled){
       stubProvider.loadStubsInModule('plunker');
    }
}]);
```

**StubProvider.js**

*This exposes an interface similar to `angular.module` to register stub services. it also looks for `stubs.json` which has the list of mock services which is loaded by halting the bootstrap. It also exposes a provide which an App can use to set up overload of existing services with the ones in the stubs.json*

```
var Stubs = {},
    modules = [];
function module(moduleName) {
    return {
        mock: function (func) {
            modules.push(func);
        }, get: function () {
            return modules;
        }
    };
}
Stubs.module = module;

loadStubs();

function loadStubs() {
    window.name = "NG_DEFER_BOOTSTRAP!";
    var injector = angular.injector(['ng']);
    var $q = injector.get('$q');
    var $http = injector.get('$http');
    var scripts = [];

    $http.get('stubs.json').then(function (result) {
        scripts = result.data.map(function (src) {
            var script = document.createElement('script');
            script.src = src;
            script.async = true;
            document.head.appendChild(script);

            var defered = $q.defer();

            script.onload = function () {
                defered.resolve();
            };
            return defered.promise;
        });

        $q.all(scripts).finally(function () {
            angular.element().ready(function () {
                angular.resumeBootstrap();
            });
        });
    });
}

//This is the provider which actually will do the overriding
angular.module('StubsApp', []).provider('stubService', function ($provide) {
    ...... //Code in plunker
});
```

**DataService Mock.js**

*This is the just a mock which actually uses Stubs interface to register the mock `Stubs.module('app').mock(MockService)` and the ctor has a property `stubFor="serviceName"` which tells which service this actually mocks*

```
function MockService($q, $log){
this.getData = function(){
       return $q.when('I am Mock!!');
  }
}
MockService.$inject = ['$q', '$log'];

MockService.stubFor="DataService";

Stubs.module('app').mock(MockService);
```

**stubs.json**

*Just a simple json file that specifies the mocks*

```
["DataServiceMock.js"]
```

**index.html**

```
<script src="app.js"></script>
<script src="DataService.js"></script>
<script src="Driver.js"></script>
<script src="stubprovider.js"></script>
```

This works fine. Now the issue is that when i move `Driver.js` file **before the service registration** i.e `DataService.js` it won't mock anymore. Specific portion of code that performs overriding in the "StubProvider.js" is

```
   Stubs.module(moduleName).get().forEach(function (mod) {
        var serviceName = mod.stubFor;
        var ctor = mod;
        if (serviceName) {
            $provide.service(serviceName, ctor);
        }
    });
```

Here is a **[Demo Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/tChomn?p=preview)** If you comment out the line in the `Driver.js` you can see the output will be from the real service other wise it will be from the mock service. And to replicate the issue in the index.html mode `Driver.js` before `DataService.js` it won't override DataService with MockDataservice.

- **Why is it that the order of config registration matter, config phase is supposed to run before the service instantiation anyways correct?**
- Is there a better pattern to ensure all the scripts are loaded before resuming the bootstrap process rather than using the deferred pattern.

Comment: I like this question because i can't answer it at the moment. I've been playing with your code and i have 1 question. Why don't you just create a new module, provide everything you want to override from the main module to the one just created, and pass that module name to the resumeBootstrap function? That way you should be able to override everything previously defined with the same names. It should be much cleaner. Another option that comes to my mind is to use decorators but i think they won't apply in your scenario. Cheers! Hope to have a better answer to give soon

Comment: One more thing to note, the angular.injector() starts the application, but i don't know what is it's behaviour when window.name is NG_DEFER_BOOTSTRAP!

Comment: @HeberLZ Thanks for your suggestion, sounds like a good idea actually. I am yet to try that. But if you get a good/better solution please post as answer.  My main thing is that i do not want to load the scripts for mock controllers in my html statically. I would instead load it dynamically. Thanks again. The idea of providing [`NG_DEFER_BOOTSTRAP!`](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap#deferred-bootstrap) is that bootstrap will not start until we call resumeBootstrap.

Comment: I think the issue is not within the bootstrapping flow, but around the injector creation. I say this because i have tried not to bootstrap the application at all synchronously but rather do the bootstrapping manually and the result is exactly the same. On the other hand, i've had to declare injectors in execution time and they work like a parallel application, that's why i think it could be the reason of this strange behaviour. Later i'll  try some things and show the results if they are positive. Cheers!

Answer (score -1):

Use the `createElement` and `appendChild` DOM methods, the `src` and `onload` attributes of the `script` element, and the `bootstrap`, `element` and `injector` methods of AngularJS:

```js
    /* Create script element */
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    /* Set src */
    script.src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.1/angular.min.js";
    /* Append to head */
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
    
    function dothis()
      {
      //local datastore
      this.mvvm = {};
    
      //template string
      var html = "<div>ID: {{$id}}</div>".replace("|",'"',"g");
      //template object
      var template = angular.element(html);
      //template transformer
      var compiler = angular.injector(["ng"]).get("$compile");
      //template result
      var linker = compiler(template);
      //scope object
      var scope = angular.injector(["ng"]).get("$rootScope");
      //scope binding
      var result = linker(scope)[0];
    
      /* Append result to body */
      document.body.appendChild(result);
    
      /* Render */
      angular.bootstrap(document, ['ng']);
      }
    
    script.onload = dothis;
```