# Manually load/unload modules with angular.bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here is my problem : I would like to make a single page application where AngularJS apps could be loaded/unloaded on the fly in a "main content" section, when clicking on different entries of a menu.

But I just can't figure out how to make this. I'm always getting the `ng:btstrpd` error when using the `angular.bootstrap` function.

I load the apps using the following code :

```
var mainContent = document.getElementById('main-content');
window.loadApp = function(modules) {
    angular.bootstrap(mainContent, modules);
}
```

Here is a jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/010b62ry/

I tried to remove the DOM element and reinsert it again but I get weird behaviors (like duplicates). I think the modules are not unloaded.
I also have tons of `<!-- ngView:  -->` comments while doing so.

Anyone has a good idea about how to implement this ? Bonus point if the memory gets released when switching from one application to another.

PS: I really need to bootstrap 100% independant modules (who manage their own routes etc) because some of them could be developed by other people who do not have access to the source code of this application. I just need to start their modules as 100% autonomous angular applications.

Comment: Possibly not closely related, i had a question posted sometime back with a different issue. It has a demo.. Not sure might provide some clues.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25537396/override-angular-services-during-config-phase-for-live-mock-feature-with-the-sam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i found this thread [How to destroy an angularjs app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14990480/how-to-destroy-an-angularjs-app). Although I added code to recreate main-content div.

HTML code:

```
<nav>
    <a onclick="loadApp(['app1'])">Load app n°1</a>
    <a onclick="loadApp(['app2'])">Load app n°2</a> 
</nav>
<div id="main-content-wrap">
    <div id="main-content" class="app">
        <div ng-view></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
angular.module('app1', ['ngRoute']);
angular.module('app1')
.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .otherwise({
        template: 'hello app n°1'
    });
}]);
angular.module('app2', ['ngRoute']);
angular.module('app2')
.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .otherwise({
        template: 'hello app n°2'
    });
}]);

var mainContent = document.getElementById('main-content');
var mainContentWrap = document.getElementById('main-content-wrap');
var mainContentHTML = mainContentWrap.innerHTML;
window.loadApp = function(modules) {
    if (window.currentApp) {
        destroyApp(window.currentApp);
        mainContentWrap.removeChild(mainContent);
        mainContentWrap.innerHTML = mainContentHTML;
        mainContent = document.getElementById('main-content');
    }
    window.currentApp = angular.bootstrap(mainContent, modules);
}

function destroyApp(app) {
    /*
* Iterate through the child scopes and kill 'em
* all, because Angular 1.2 won't let us $destroy()
* the $rootScope
*/
    var $rootScope = app.get('$rootScope');
    var scope = $rootScope.$$childHead;
    while (scope) {
        var nextScope = scope.$$nextSibling;
        scope.$destroy();
        scope = nextScope;
    }

    /*
* Iterate the properties of the $rootScope and delete 
* any that possibly were set by us but leave the 
* Angular-internal properties and functions intact so we 
* can re-use the application.
*/
    for(var prop in $rootScope){
        if (($rootScope[prop]) 
            && (prop.indexOf('$$') != 0) 
            && (typeof($rootScope[prop]) === 'object')
           ) {
            $rootScope[prop] = null;
        }
    }
}
```

And Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/010b62ry/5/

It works but it looks like a black magic. I think it is much better to have one app and several controllers.